# Instalar dependencia que no tiene archivo package.json

Tags: nodejs, npm, composer, bower

Cómo se podrá instalar con **npm** o con **bower** algún proyecto en github el cual no tenga archivo package.json, por ejemplo, en composer se pueden crear un package de la siguiente manera:

```
{
...
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "library": true,
            "package": {
                "name": "mevdschee/php-api-auth",
                "version": "1",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/mevdschee/php-api-auth.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "files": [
                        "auth.php"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "mevdschee/php-api-auth": "1",
        "mevdschee/php-crud-api": "^1.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "mustache/mustache": "^2.12",
        "google/apiclient": "2.0"
    },
...
}
```

Existe algún equivalente en nodeJS para esta acción?

Comment: Intentaste a con npm install  paquete o con bower install paquete ??

Comment: ¿Cual paquete específicamente? si se encuentra entre los paquetes de npm o bower solo utiliza despues install tupaquete, si fuera el caso de que no se encuentra registrado, necesitaras instalar git